# how to have the return answer as a whole number

Tags: javascript, int

I'm a beginner in javascript and I just made this program as an exercise that can basically guess your number in 7 tries or less, but the problem is that i keep getting the (Answer Variable) as a decimal number and I want it to be only a whole number. How do I do that ?

`````
console.log('I will guess the number you\'re thinking of in 7 guesses maximum\n\t\tThink of a number between 1 and 100')
console.log('\n\n')

let low = 0;
let high = 100;
let answer = (high + low) / 2
let guess = Number(prompt("Pick a number"))


for(let a = 1; a < 7; a++){
 console.log(`Is your number ${answer} ?`) 
  let ud = Number(prompt(`Press :  1-Larger,  2-Smaller,   3-Current Number`))
    if(ud == 1){
      low=answer
      answer=(high + low) / 2
    } else if (ud == 2){
      high=answer
      answer=(high + low) / 2
    } else if (ud == "c"){
      break;
    }
}
console.log(`This is magic`); ````
`````

Comment: use ```Math.round()``` have you tried that!!

Answer (score 0):

That is because if you devide an odd number by 2 it will always give a decimal number. You can use `Math.floor`

```js
console.log('I will guess the number you\'re thinking of in 7 guesses maximum\n\t\tThink of a number between 1 and 100')
console.log('\n\n')

let low = 0;
let high = 100;
let answer = (high + low) / 2
let guess = Number(prompt("Pick a number"))


for (let a = 1; a < 7; a++) {
  console.log(`Is your number ${answer} ?`)
  let ud = Number(prompt(`Press :  1-Larger,  2-Smaller,   3-Current Number`))
  if (ud == 1) {
    low = answer
    answer = Math.floor((high + low) / 2)
  } else if (ud == 2) {
    high = answer
    answer = Math.floor((high + low) / 2)
  } else if (ud == "c") {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(`This is magic`);
```